# meta-description for "tag" and "categories" pages

Tags: metadata, meta-tags, hexo

For HEXO blog... I know that meta-description is written in config file and works across all pages.

For blogposts I can create individual meta-descriptions and that works for the search engines.

However, my "tag" and "categories" pages get indexed now and with meta-description of home-page.
This is not good.

So I am asking if it is possible to create a custom meta-description for "tag" and "categories" pages?
Something like... 
`description: this is a page about {{tag}}`

and

`description: this is a page about {{category}}`

This is the code in my `head.ejs`.
The site main config file has `description: main config meta-description text`.

```html
<%if(metaDescription){%>
<meta name="description" content="<%= config.description %>">
    <% } else if (page.description){ %>
      <meta name="description" content="<%= page.description %>">
      <% } else if (page.excerpt){ %>
      <meta name="description" content="<%= strip_html(page.excerpt).replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '').replace(/[\n,\r]/g,'') %>">
      <% } else if (page.content){ %>
      <meta name="description" content="<%= strip_html(page.content).replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '').substring(0, 150).replace(/[\n,\r]/g,'') %>">
      <% } else if (config.description){ %>
      <meta name="description" content="<%= config.description %>">
      <% } 
      <% if (page.keywords){ %>
        <meta name="keywords" content="<%= page.keywords %>">
      <% } else if (page.tags){ %>
      <%
        var thistags=[];
        page.tags.each(function(k){ 
        thistags.push(k.name);
        }) %>
        <meta name="keywords" content="<%= thistags %>">
      <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all handled by your theme so you need to add the logic there.

You need to check if your page is a tag or category index and generate a custom description there:

```
let description = page.description; // Normal case when your desc comes from meta data


else if (page.tag) {
    description = 'This is a page about ' + page.tag;
} else if (page.category) {
    description = 'This is a page about ' + page.category;
}

// Use your description variable as you are currently doing
```

EDIT: based on post update (added `head.ejs`)

```
else if (page.tag) {
  <meta name="description" content="<%= 'This is a page about ' + page.tag %>">
} else if (page.category) {
    <meta name="description" content="<%= 'This is a page about ' + page.category %>">
}
```

Comment: Hi... I already learned a lot from your blog... http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/03/Create-an-Hexo-Theme-Part-1-Index/ - nice to see you here also... :) About the description, makes sense, but where to implement this exactly? I have a posts overview page and this takes the logic from `archive.ejs`, my `tags` page and I assume `categories` page also takes the logic from my `archive.ejs` partial, so I would add above code in `archieve.ejs`? And either way the default `meta-description` still works for NON-tag and NON-categories because I set that in my main `config` file, correct?

Comment: If you meta-description comes from the config, perfect. The rest of the logic should be implement wherever you need it: in your case probably `head.ejs` or something like that.

Comment: does not work... the meta-description from the main config file overrides it all.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code with the actual meta-description tag ?

Comment: added my current `head.ejs` in SO post.